# unknown column in projection appear in SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite

i'm trying to make a database but it does not work ( the app force to stop ). i try to check in the log cat and the error is "unknown column in projection" and it suggest me to check the MyToDoContentProvider.java.  i'll already check my MyToDoContentProvider.java with my SQLite statement but i dont know what wrong with it. can anyone help me? tq..

this is my MyToDoContentProvider.java

```
package com.date.contentprovider;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;

import android.content.ContentProvider;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.UriMatcher;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQueryBuilder;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import com.date.database.FirstClass;
import com.date.database.TodoDatabaseHelper;

public class MyTodoContentProvider extends ContentProvider {

// database
private TodoDatabaseHelper database;

// Used for the UriMacher
private static final int TODOS = 10;
private static final int TODO_ID = 20;

private static final String AUTHORITY = "com.date.contentprovider";

private static final String BASE_PATH = "todos";
public static final Uri CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://" + AUTHORITY
  + "/" + BASE_PATH);

public static final String CONTENT_TYPE = ContentResolver.CURSOR_DIR_BASE_TYPE
  + "/todos";
public static final String CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE = ContentResolver.CURSOR_ITEM_BASE_TYPE
  + "/todo";

private static final UriMatcher sURIMatcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);
static {
sURIMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, BASE_PATH, TODOS);
sURIMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, BASE_PATH + "/#", TODO_ID);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreate() {
database = new TodoDatabaseHelper(getContext());
return false;
}

@Override
public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection,
  String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {

// Uisng SQLiteQueryBuilder instead of query() method
SQLiteQueryBuilder queryBuilder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();

// Check if the caller has requested a column which does not exists
checkColumns(projection);

// Set the table
queryBuilder.setTables(FirstClass.TABLE_TODO);

int uriType = sURIMatcher.match(uri);
switch (uriType) {
case TODOS:
  break;
case TODO_ID:
  // Adding the ID to the original query
  queryBuilder.appendWhere(FirstClass.COLUMN_ID + "="
      + uri.getLastPathSegment());
  break;
default:
  throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI: " + uri);
}

SQLiteDatabase db = database.getWritableDatabase();
Cursor cursor = queryBuilder.query(db, projection, selection,
    selectionArgs, null, null, sortOrder);
// Make sure that potential listeners are getting notified
cursor.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), uri);

return cursor;
}

@Override
public String getType(Uri uri) {
return null;
}

@Override
public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues values) {
int uriType = sURIMatcher.match(uri);
SQLiteDatabase sqlDB = database.getWritableDatabase();
int rowsDeleted = 0;
long id = 0;
switch (uriType) {
case TODOS:
  id = sqlDB.insert(FirstClass.TABLE_TODO, null, values);
  break;
default:
  throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI: " + uri);
}
getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
return Uri.parse(BASE_PATH + "/" + id);
}

@Override
public int delete(Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
int uriType = sURIMatcher.match(uri);
SQLiteDatabase sqlDB = database.getWritableDatabase();
int rowsDeleted = 0;
switch (uriType) {
case TODOS:
  rowsDeleted = sqlDB.delete(FirstClass.TABLE_TODO, selection,
      selectionArgs);
  break;
case TODO_ID:
  String id = uri.getLastPathSegment();
  if (TextUtils.isEmpty(selection)) {
    rowsDeleted = sqlDB.delete(FirstClass.TABLE_TODO,
            FirstClass.COLUMN_ID + "=" + id, 
        null);
  } else {
    rowsDeleted = sqlDB.delete(FirstClass.TABLE_TODO,
            FirstClass.COLUMN_ID + "=" + id 
        + " and " + selection,
        selectionArgs);
  }
  break;
 default:
  throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI: " + uri);
 }
 getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
 return rowsDeleted;
}

@Override
public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues values, String selection,
  String[] selectionArgs) {

int uriType = sURIMatcher.match(uri);
SQLiteDatabase sqlDB = database.getWritableDatabase();
int rowsUpdated = 0;
switch (uriType) {
case TODOS:
  rowsUpdated = sqlDB.update(FirstClass.TABLE_TODO, 
      values, 
      selection,
      selectionArgs);
  break;
case TODO_ID:
  String id = uri.getLastPathSegment();
  if (TextUtils.isEmpty(selection)) {
    rowsUpdated = sqlDB.update(FirstClass.TABLE_TODO, 
        values,
        FirstClass.COLUMN_ID + "=" + id, 
        null);
  } else {
    rowsUpdated = sqlDB.update(FirstClass.TABLE_TODO, 
        values,
        FirstClass.COLUMN_ID + "=" + id 
        + " and " 
        + selection,
        selectionArgs);
  }
  break;
default:
  throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI: " + uri);
}
getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
return rowsUpdated;
}

private void checkColumns(String[] projection) {
String[] available = { FirstClass.COLUMN_NAME,
        FirstClass.COLUMN_DESCRIPTION, FirstClass.COLUMN_CATEGORY,     FirstClass.COLUMN_TRIGGER,
        FirstClass.COLUMN_MON, FirstClass.COLUMN_TUE, FirstClass.COLUMN_WED, FirstClass.COLUMN_THU,
        FirstClass.COLUMN_FRI, FirstClass.COLUMN_SAT, FirstClass.COLUMN_SUN, FirstClass.COLUMN_DATE,
        FirstClass.COLUMN_TIME, FirstClass.COLUMN_LATITUDE, FirstClass.COLUMN_LONGITUDE, 
        FirstClass.COLUMN_STATUS };


if (projection != null) {
  HashSet<String> requestedColumns = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(projection));
  HashSet<String> availableColumns = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(available));
  // Check if all columns which are requested are available
  if (!availableColumns.containsAll(requestedColumns)) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown columns in projection");
  }
}
```

}

}

and this is my FirstClass.java

```
package com.date.database;

import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.util.Log;

public class FirstClass {
 // Database table
  public static final String TABLE_TODO = "todo";
  public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
  public static final String COLUMN_CATEGORY = "category";
  public static final String COLUMN_NAME = "name";
  public static final String COLUMN_DESCRIPTION = "description";
  public static final String COLUMN_TRIGGER ="trigger";
  public static final String COLUMN_MON = "mon";
  public static final String COLUMN_TUE = "tue";
  public static final String COLUMN_WED = "wed";
  public static final String COLUMN_THU = "thu";
  public static final String COLUMN_FRI ="fri";
  public static final String COLUMN_SAT = "sat";
  public static final String COLUMN_SUN = "sun";
  public static final String COLUMN_DATE = "date";
  public static final String COLUMN_TIME = "time";
  public static final String COLUMN_LATITUDE ="latitude";
  public static final String COLUMN_LONGITUDE= "longitude";
  public static final String COLUMN_STATUS = "status";



  // Database creation SQL statement
  private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table " 
      + TABLE_TODO
      + "(" 
      + COLUMN_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, " 
      + COLUMN_CATEGORY + " text not null, " 
      + COLUMN_NAME + " text not null," 
      + COLUMN_DESCRIPTION + " text not null," 
      + COLUMN_TRIGGER + " text not null ,"//'t', "
      + COLUMN_MON + " integer not null , "// == 1,"
      + COLUMN_TUE + " integer not null , "//== 2,"
      + COLUMN_WED + " integer not null , "// == 3,"
      + COLUMN_THU + " integer not null , "// == 4,"
      + COLUMN_FRI + " integer not null , "// == 5,"
      + COLUMN_SAT + " integer not null , "// == 6,"
      + COLUMN_SUN + " integer not null , "// == 0,"
      + COLUMN_DATE + " date not null,"
      + COLUMN_TIME + " time not null,"
      + COLUMN_LATITUDE + " decimal not null , "// ==0.00000000,"
      + COLUMN_LONGITUDE + " decimal not null , "// ==0.00000000,"
      + COLUMN_STATUS + " text not null  "// 'act' "
      + ");";

  public static void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
    database.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);

  }

  public static void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase database, int oldVersion,
      int newVersion) {
    Log.w(FirstClass.class.getName(), "Upgrading database from version "
        + oldVersion + " to " + newVersion
        + ", which will destroy all old data");
    database.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_TODO);
   // database.execSQL("INSERT INTO "+TABLE_TODO+" VALUES (null, datetime()) ");
    onCreate(database);
  }
```

}

this is my TodoDatabaseHelper.java

```
package com.date.database;


import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class TodoDatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

  private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "todotable.db";
  private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
  final int oldVersion =1;
  final int newVersion =1;


  public TodoDatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
  }

  // Method is called during creation of the database
  @Override
  public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
    FirstClass.onCreate(database);
  }

  // Method is called during an upgrade of the database,
  // e.g. if you increase the database version
  @Override
  public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase database, int oldVersion,
      int newVersion) {
    FirstClass.onUpgrade(database, oldVersion, newVersion);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the point where you are querying the database. You must be asking for a column which doesn't exist in that particular table.

Comment: all column that i'm asking is already declare in the table.. thats why i'm very confuse..

Comment: Then check if the OnCreate() method in your FirstClass is being executed.

Comment: @user1858863, What was your problem?

Comment: i miss to call one column in the MyToDoContentProvider.java and the column is important. my bad..

Comment: why my data cannot be save?